# OKEX and OKCoin Spot Price APIs

Tags: json, rest, api

Im am interested in the Spot Price APIS of OKEX and OKCoin

Their API description is here:

https://www.okcoin.com/rest_api.html

https://www.okex.com/rest_api.html

All price REST APIs require a market parameter (symbol=...), for example:

GET https://www.okex.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=ltc_btc

My question: is there an API that lists the markets in a way that I get all valid parameters for the price API like ltc_btc? I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you want a list of symbols which are traded on this exchange. You may find it here:
okcoin: https://www.okcoin.com/v2/markets/products
okex:  https://www.okex.com/v2/markets/products

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good starting point. The results appear to be limited to five markets. How do I get all markets? Where do I get the description of these v2 APIs?

Comment: I found the answers - okcoin has only five markets and the description is here :-) https://www.okcoin.cn/html/okcoin_cn_etc_api.html#api-MarketData-getCurrencyPairsUsingGET

Comment: Those 5 markets belong to okcoin. Okex markets are on okex exchange:) https://www.okex.com/v2/markets/products

Comment: You should update the answer, so the right link is in it and not just in the comments